# joomla Administrator Site Off-Line

Tags: joomla

I want to access the `configuration.php` file from a custom front-end module. I want to set `var $offline` to o or 1 from the module(through radio) and then refresh page. I also want the module to show when the site is off line.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question is too short and lacks detail. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: The downside to this is that once you make the site 'offline' and refresh from the front end, you won't be able to do anything without going to the backend (or into configuration via ftp or ssh or whatever) and setting it back online.  Unless you code for that of course... seems like more work to do that than just going offline on the backend to me... but are you looking for someone to make this module for you?  Or have you made one and have a question?  I don't get the point of this...

Comment: When the site is 'offline' it isn't totally inaccessible. Once logged in through the front end - which a Super Admin can still do even when a site is 'offline' - this could be doable. Only thing I'm unsure of is whether the configuration file can be saved using correct Joomla code from front-end. It would seem to me that it would be trivial for a module to edit the configuration file using simple PHP - read file in, regex search and replace, save file out. Ah - modules don't receive input, you'd need a component (or perhaps plugin) to receive the submitted data and action it.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand, if you want to set some message on the front end when the site is offline then simply follow the steps:

1. login on admin pannel.
2. hover the mouse on the site menu on the top of the admin pannel.
3. click on the `global configuration` menu.
4. in the site tab, you will find the site settings and the radio button with yes, and no and the offline message the you want to display when the site is offline.
5. if you want to show the offline message the simple click on the `yes` radio button and save it..

thats it..

Comment: The OP asked for a front-end module to accomplish this - not the traditional method through the backend.